# How to deactivate/remove/unpublish my company page from Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: support, jobs

I've added my company page in Stack Overflow Careers and now I'v decided to remove it.

Is there a way to remove/deactivate/unpublish my company page from Stack Overflow Careers?

Comment: Email to the team is your best bet.

Comment: Really. there is no "Deactivate" button ????

Comment: Most likely there isn't. Same way that users can't delete their account with a single click after having some activity, but rather need to contact the team and request deletion

Comment: this is different. I want to hide that page from public

Comment: Well, I'm not sure since I never added any company page, I'm just sharing my best guess based on my experience with Stack Exchange and Careers. If you'll wait, a dev will show up eventually and give official response. :)

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much. I'll wait for them. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard You were right. I sent them an email and they take care of it.

Comment: Cheers, good to be right. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To unpublish or delete your company page, just send an email to careers@stackoverflow.com and we'll take care of it for you!

Comment: Good. But i'd rather to have this option for my own. ;)